# Wix msi won't work. Particular msi's do

Tags: wix, windows-installer, exe

This is my first question in this forum.

I've build several msi's for my installer.
All of them work.
But if I put them together with the bootstrapper the exe-File won't install the files inside of the msi's.

The Installer then starts shows that it is working on the particular msi's but in the end no new file is on the system.

Can anybody help?

Greez

Comment: Please be more specific and add errors and/or logs to the question.

Comment: There aren't any errors. Maybe I can provide an log tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your clue.

By reading the log I found out that the exe writes to another drive than the single msi's do.
I don't know weather this is a "clean" solution but for me hardcoding the TARGETDIR to "D:\" does the job. All files are copied to the destinationfolder.

```
<Property Id="TARGETDIR">D:\</Property>
```

Before that I had used a custom action to change the rootdirectory.
That worked for the single msi's but not for the exe.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It's great you managed to troubleshoot your problem with the help of logs, however this thread is unlikely to be of any help or hint to others facing the similar type of errors. Please, consider either modifying your answer to provide more useful details, or deleting the thread altogether.

Comment: I added some explanation